# Unable to Connect Sqoop to Oracle TimesTen through JDBC on Linux

Tags: linux, jdbc, connection, sqoop, timesten

I have installed Timesten database (full version) on linux (Linux is guest OS installed through Oracle viritual box with cloudera VM)

I am trying to run following sqoop command on linux and getting below errors

**command**

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:timesten:direct:dsn=sampledb_1122 --driver com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver


**error**

ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbc in java.library.path
java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbc in java.library.path
    at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1809)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:305)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:161)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:878)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.listTables(SqlManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Could not retrieve tables list from server
18/02/18 18:56:04 ERROR tool.ListTablesTool: manager.listTables() returned null
```

TimesTen bin and lib folder location

/home/cloudra/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/bin
/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib

Following values are setup in my environment and other parameters

```
USERNAME=cloudera
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/cloudera
PATH=/var/lib/sqoop:/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/bin:/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib:/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin:/var/lib/sqoop:/home/cloudra/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/bin:/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib:/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin:/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/firefox:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/cloudera/bin
PWD=/home/cloudera
THREAD_FLAGS=native
HOME=/home/cloudera
SHLVL=2
M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=cloudera
CVS_RSH=ssh
CLASSPATH=/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib/ttjdbc6.jar

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib:/home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib:

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ 

cloudera@quickstart bin]$ ./ttversion 
TimesTen Release 11.2.2.8.0 (64 bit Linux/x86_64) (tt1122_64:53396) 2015-01-20T08:36:31Z
  Instance admin: cloudera
  Instance home directory: /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64
  World accessible
  Daemon home directory: /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/info
  PL/SQL enabled.
```

In addition to above.. the ttjdbc6.jar file is located at following location

```
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$ pwd
/var/lib/sqoop
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$ ls -ltr
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Jun  9  2015 mysql-connector-java.jar -> /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Feb 16 21:37 ttjdbc6.jar -> /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib/ttjdbc6.jar

[cloudera@quickstart timesten]$ pwd
/usr/lib/timesten
[cloudera@quickstart timesten]$ ls -ltr
total 276
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 279580 Feb 18 11:33 ttjdbc6.jar
```

Java_library_path output

```
[cloudera@quickstart timesten]$ java -XshowSettings:properties
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib/ttjdbc6.jar
    java.class.version = 51.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext
        /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib
        /home/cloudera/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122_64/lib

        /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_67-b01
```

I execute ttenv.sh scripts but it is not setting up any parameter when I check env parameters, so I had to do it manually.

Gurus and experts.. please help me here.. not sure what is the issue and why I am getting the above error.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

The key line here is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: 
  no ttJdbc in java.library.path
```

The TimesTen JDBC driver is a type 1 / 2 driver and it relies on the underlying TimesTen native libraries. Specifically it needs several shared libraries located in `<TimesTen_install_dir>/lib` such as `libttJdbc.so` (the one that the error is complaining about), `libtten.so` etc. Typically you need to make sure that the `java.library.path` includes this directory (which it appears is the case) and that the `CLASSPATH` includes the `ttjdbc7.jar` file in that directory. Another possibility is that your TimesTen installation is a 'client only' installation in which case you cannot use the 'direct' driver and if you try to do so then you would get this exact error. I suggest checking to see if you actually have the files `libttJdbc.so` and `libtten.so` in `<TimesTen_install_dir>/lib` and if not, then this means you have a client only install and need to configure / use client/server connectivity instead.